# If Cell Matches another Cell, Copy Value

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have two work sheets with some of the same ids, but if an id matches on one sheet with another I need it to see if the status is Routed and if it is, then I need a y placed in Column B of the related number.

So for example:

```
Worksheet 1  
-----A--------B  
1--**4345**---Routed  
2--5643---Completed  
3--3423---Routed  
4--2342---Routed  



Worksheet 2  
-----A-------B  
1--9876----n  
2--5678----n  
3--**4345**----y  
4--1234----n
```

So if there is a match in column A between the two worksheets then I need it to search for Routed in Column B on Worksheet 1.

If the word Routed is there, then I need it to add a "y" to the previously matched id in column B of Worksheet 2, otherwise if the id is not found or if it matches, but no routed (rather it be blank or something else [completed, done, ect]) then I need an n in column B.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `VLOOKUP()` function into an `IF()` function will test whether the looked-up value meets the specified condition, and return the specified values if `TRUE` (`"y"`) or `FALSE` ("`n`"): `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, SHEET1!$A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE)="Routed", "y", "n")`. You can enclose the entire formula in `IFERROR()` to account for IDs in Sheet2 that are not in Sheet1: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2, SHEET1!$A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE)="Routed", "y", "n"), "n")`.

Per comments: If you want to find any cell containing the text `"Routed"` (but possibly with other text as well), you can change the `VLOOKUP(. . .) = "Routed"` condition to a test of whether the `SEARCH()` function finds the text: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Routed", VLOOKUP(A2, SHEET1!$A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE))), "y", "n")`. Again, you can enclose this in `IFERROR()`.

Comment: I keep getting we found a problem with this formula. I've never used formulas because I always get this error. Anyway to incorporate it into a macro?

Here I have it creating the routed column for me.
   ' Convert to Number
   range("A1:A1000") = range("A1:A1000").Value
   ' End Convert to Number
   ' Add route
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Routed?"
    range("B7").Select
   ' End route

Comment: Sorry I had to add ' to the beginning and end of my sheet names, but now it says this operation can't be performed and asks me to open an Excel workbook?

Comment: @IFeelYourPain: You likely just need to replace the sheet name & cell references with the sheet name & cell ranges for _your workbook_ instead of the sample formula I posted (if you refer to a sheet that doesn't exist in your current workbook, Excel will prompt you to find the appropriate workbook, but usually you just need to fix the formula). You need to enclose the sheet name with apostrophes if there is a space in the sheet name (and it never hurts to do so).

Comment: Does it matter that there is additional information beside Routed? It varies on what's next to it, but I keep getting n placed there instead of y when it should match. Like Routed:text/numbers

Comment: @IFeelYourPain: Yes, this formula looks for an exact match in the condition `VLOOKUP(...) = "Routed"`. I've edited the answer to include a formula for finding any cell _containing_ the text `"Routed"`.

Comment: Yea it still isn't working for me. I tried in just the regular document, but it shows n for everything. + I am wondering if it will even work in my macro, because I have the B column being made in the macro, and adding routed   textto B1 in the formula

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Without seeing your data and formula (a screenshot or two of your actual data and formula input would be useful for troubleshooting), I can only assume that you need to *update the sheet and cell references* to match your data. Using a macro for this task seems far more complicated (unnecessarily so) than understanding how to correctly reference this formula, but if that works for you, then by all means use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Place the below formula in Sheet2.  You can paste it down as many rows as you like as it is relative.

```
=IF(NOT(A1=Sheet1!A1),"",IF(Sheet1!B1="routed","y","n"))
```